# How to configure a child logger with a lower loglevel than the root level in Log4net

Tags: log4net

The app I'm working on uses a library that generates a lot of INFO level messages I don't want to log. But the rest of the app and libraries produce INFO level messages I need to log.

How can I setup log4net so that all INFO messages are logged except for one logger that need to log only at WARN or above ? All messages need to be logged in the same files.

Julien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="someappender" />
</root>
<logger name="AnotherLogger">
  <level value="WARN" />
</logger>
```

Comment: I don't know how I have missed this, thought I tried it but I guess I didn't. 

Anyway, thanks a lot, that works.

Comment: Its always like that. Sometimes you look really hard and the obvious just alludes you.