# log4net for WCF REST

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have written WCF REST Service. Now I need to enable logging. I am using **log4net** but nothing is logging in my database.

I have gone through following links but all in vain.

1. [How to configure a child logger with a lower loglevel than the root level in Log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524547/how-to-configure-a-child-logger-with-a-lower-loglevel-than-the-root-level-in-log)
2. [Log4Net in WCF not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602126/log4net-in-wcf-not-working)
3. [Log4net Issue inside wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088571/log4net-issue-inside-wcf)
4. [Log4Net with WCF Running As Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310706/log4net-with-wcf-running-as-service)

I am using **ADONetAppender**. Here is my `log4net.config` file.

```
<appender name="ADONetAppenderMessageLog" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="100" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="Data Source=FAIZAN;Initial Catalog=AnasageLogging;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
  <!--  <commandText value="INSERT INTO MessageLog ([TransactionID],[SessionID],[UserID],[Message],[MessageType],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ApplicationID]) VALUES (@transactionId, @sessionId, @userId, @message, @messageType, @createdTime,@createdBy,@applicationId)" />-->
  <commandText value="spMessageLogInsert" />
  <commandType value="StoredProcedure"/>

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@transactionId"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="80"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{Transaction_ID}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@sessionId"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{Session_ID}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@userId"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="80"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{User_ID}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="10000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{Message}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@messageType"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{Message_Type}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@createdTime"/>
    <dbType value="DateTime"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@createdBy"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{Created_By}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@applicationId"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{Application_ID}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

Here is how I am using it.

```
static log4net.Util.LogicalThreadContextProperties properties = log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties;
private static log4net.ILog log { get; set; }

public static void Write( object session_id, object user_id, object message, object message_type, object created_by, object msg)
 {
     properties["Session_ID"] = session_id;
     properties["User_ID"] = user_id;
     properties["Message"] = message;
     properties["Message_Type"] = message_type;
     properties["Created_By"] = created_by;
     log.Info(msg);
 }
```

**NOTE:** This is my wrapper class function. 
Every thing is working fine, No exception is thrown. But when I see my database table, it is empty. I am testing it on my local machine not on production. I don't know what I am missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I can see many parameters in the configuration being not set in your code properties list. Probably if you clear those parameters from the configuration file and from the stored procedure parameter list, I hope it can help you. Though I am not so sure about it. Eg: `@applicationId`, `@createdTime`, `@transactionId`

Comment: Couldn't understand! Where to remove?

Comment: It may help to enable log4net debug logging to see if any errors are occurring within log4net.

Comment: I meant to remove the parameter tags in config file like `<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@transactionId"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="80"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{Transaction_ID}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>`
And from the Stored Procedure parameter list of `spMessageLogInsert`

Comment: No no! It can't be removed, Code take these parameters from Config file.

Comment: Can you check where is the problem more specifically? Put a breakpoint on log.Info row. If it gets hit your wrapper class is fine. Start Sql Profiler, do you see call of the stored procedure? If not, probably INFO logging not enabled. If yes, check procedure parameters if there are expected values and that query succeeded.

Comment: Did you fix it. I have WCF REST service but log4net is not working...

Comment: @Ziggler Don't remember right now as question was posted 4 years ago from now. However, I am using **log4j** right now :-)

Comment: Ok... Faizan… I was able to fix my issue.....

Comment: Glad to hear this!